# Defining AKKA Actor hierarchies

Tags: akka

Understand all AKKA Actors are derived from /user guardian Actor. In order to take care of the exceptions, I would like to define MyAppParent Actor and have all my actors under this Actor. Is it possible to do this using AKKA. In Realtime I need to sending messages directly to the child Actors mailbox under MyAppParentActor and not through the parent Actor. Any pointers on how to do this if it is possible with AKKA.

Thanks,
cabear

Answer (score 1):

Just started looking into Akka. From my understanding (correct me I am wrong) to your question. Akka has a hierarchy. Root guardian -> user guardian -> your actor hierarchy. So if you want to create a top level actor (children of user guardian).

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("mySystem");
ActorRef ref = system.actorOf(Props.create(TopLevelActor.class);
```

Now if you want to create a child actor for the above created top level actor. Instead of 'system' use the actors context.
eg

```
getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ChildOfTopLevel.class)).tell(
                    new Message(0, 200000), getSelf());
```

You can use the tell method like above to instruct a top level actor to send messages to its child that you just created. Also the message won't go directly to child it will go the mailbox.

*So I think you just have to look into **context** and **tell**.*

You should read the official documentation (http://akka.io/docs/). It's pretty detailed. Also, I am still on the third chapter of the documentation so correct me if I got this wrong.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to send a message outside of the TopLevelActor class to the child class

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I think my answer above is pretty clear. We can send messages from Actor to its children and get the responses back. So you create a hierarchy of actors (useful for supervising purpose). Child of top level actor can spawn their own children and then those children can spawn even more children of their own. I think you should look at the documentation or follow any basic tutorial. This is useful http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/reactive-programming-akka